# importing bulk images in Magento 1.9.3.1

Tags: product-images, importexport, magento1.9.3.1

I am trying to import images against my previously uploaded products but it is not going through. I read many articles and blogs on this topic but every one is suggesting to keep images in media/import/ folder but there is no import folder in /media/ in Magento 1.9.3.1 version. No body talks about this if import folder is not there then do we need to create /import folder or not. I even tried all steps after creating import folder but it is not processing images.
Now my images are kept like this:
/media/import/abcd.jpg
I have even given 777 permission to media folder and same to import folder but every time it comes with an error saying that images could not be found. My csv sheet is having following column ::

**sku | image | small_image | Theumbnail**

I tried almost all folders but I could not import my images. Now I am stuck and have no idea how to handle this situation.

I am sure you guys have also faced this issue in past and might have solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a forward slash in your spreadsheet before each image name?
Are you importing just one image per sku?

have you saved your opened your import file with a text editor and then saved it as something.csv utf8